# Octave, display image received by socket connection does't show

Tags: image, sockets, octave

I have an octave script in which i open a socket server an receive some commands from connected clients. This already works. Now i need to send data to Octave, mostly images and process them. To test this i wanted to receive and display a grayscale test image.

```
bufflen = 4096;
[data,count]=recv(b,bufflen);
imshow (data)
```

the image window opens but it is empty. The size of data is exactly the size of the image file i am sending. I also tried saving the image with

```
imwrite (data, "test.jpg");
```

this produced a file but every line of the image was in one long line. When i open the image with

```
imshow test.jpg
```

everything works as it should, the image window appears and shows the image.

I am sending the data via netcat with

```
>ncat.exe 127.0.0.1 12346 < test.jpg
```

this seems to work, i was able to transfer the image to another pc and view it there.

Every hint or tip is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you need help debugging your code you have to create a example which can be run by someone who tries to help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve And you didn't even mention which octave package you are using for the socket connection...

Comment: I am using octave 4.2.1 on win7 with the new build in sockets package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending your jpeg as byte stream (`ncat.exe 127.0.0.1 12346 < test.jpg`) but you are trying to show is with `imshow` as it would be an uncompressed RGB, grayscale or index image. You can receive it and save it to a tempfile and then load it with imread. In this case graphics/image-magick will do the uncompression from JPE to RGB to you.

Comment: But now i have an other problem, seems like the input buffer on the Octave sockets  recv cant be bigger than 4608 bytes. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Jan, I also answered your other socket related question on the help mailinglist. There is no "4608 byte" limit and very likely a problem in your code. Please create a new question with MCVE. Please add used OS, Octave version and used socket package and version

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here since you didn't provide much information, but it sounds like you're data is coming as a vector and you need to reshape it into an array for `imshow`

```
>> newdata = reshape(data, 64, 64)
```

You haven't shown us an example of the input data, so it is also possible that your data is a string of characters, while image arrays need to be numerical values. To verify before reshaping you could run:

```
>> class(data)
```

If so you will need to convert it to an array of numerical values. You can use `str2num` for that, but exactly how to do so will depend on what the string looks like, are there value separators, etc.

See:

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/String-Conversions.html

Comment: this did not work, i got error: reshape: can't reshape 1x1918 array to 512x512 array. The exact numbers may be incorrect. But the problem is at leas I think, that Octave dont understand it is an image but treats it as raw input strem.

Comment: an image in octave is just an array of numbers.  how would you turn a 1x1918 array into 512x512?  if it's really 512x512 you should have 512x512=262,144 values. You said your buffer length was 4096 so I was guessing that you were expecting a 64x64 greyscale image (64x64 = 4096 pixels, each would be an integer).  The problem is you currently don't have an image. you have a stream of data and need to turn it back into an image array.

Comment: just seeing Andy's comment above. Yes, if you're sending a binary jpeg, that would be the problem. As Andy said in his first comment, providing better detail in your question would help get to an answer faster.