# Octave, convert uin8 array to image

Tags: image, sockets, octave

A couple of days ago i asked a similar question here

[Octave, display image received by socket connection does't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029568/octave-display-image-received-by-socket-connection-doest-show)

The reason I now ask a new question for that, is that i wanted to know if there is a faster way to convert a uint8 array containing an image to an actual Octave image 'object'.

```
pkg load sockets;

function [b,rcv_sck] = openSocket
    rcv_sck=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    bind(rcv_sck,12345);
    a=listen(rcv_sck,0);
    b=accept(rcv_sck);
end

[b,rcv_sck] = openSocket;
data = recv (b, Inf, MSG_WAITALL);

disconnect (b);
disconnect (rcv_sck);

imshow(data) % does not work

fileID = fopen('data.tiff','w');
fwrite('data.tiff', data);
fclose(fileID);
im = imread('data.tiff');

#imshow(im) % works like supposed
```

This is what i do:

I have a socket server running in Octave which receives a stream of data. This data are mostly images and have to be processed as images. In my example i call "imshow()" two times, the second one is in the last line and commented. my problem is, octave cant process the raw uint8 byte stream as an image, as already answered by Andy in my first post:

> You are sending your jpeg as byte stream [..] but you are trying to show is with imshow as it would be an uncompressed RGB, grayscale or index image. You can receive it and save it to a tempfile and then load it with imread. In this case graphics/image-magick will do the uncompression from JPE to RGB to you.

This was a nice trick and as you can test in the example above works fine, but i wanted to ask if there is a faster way, without the need of slow file I/O?

Thanks again for reading all this!

Comment: after your third question I guess this is a typical XY-problem (if you've never heard of it please read http://xyproblem.info/). Apparently you want to transfer different image files (in the last question JPEG, in this question TIFF) from one windoze machine to another windoze machine and only view it on the receiving machine. I really hope you don't want to mimic some video streaming where MJPEG would be appropriate. Or perhaps the best solution would be to run a very lightweight http server on machine A and use in Octave `imread (URL)` on machine B to get the image...

Comment: i did not know about the xy problem, thanks for pointing that out. In my opinion though my questions are perfectly credible :) I have two different technical systems running on the same machine that need to communicate. One is LabVIEW operating a complex image acquisition machine, the other one needs to be Octave where these images get  analyzed and the computed values are sent back to LabVIEW. I thought that communication via sockets would be nice. It is fast, reliable (once it works) and the Octave scripts could be changed easily. If you have a better idea, please tell me.

Comment: why not do the file-sending via ssh at the os level (i.e. via a bash script using `scp` or whatever), and only let octave do the image processing?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou As far as I understand he wants a data exchange between LabVIEW and GNU Octave which are both running on the same windoze machine so scp isn't even necessary. Perhaps he wants something like https://github.com/KaeroDot/GOLPI (which is communication via pipes (of course whith all the included problems))